# "Universal" search engine for PHP examples

Tags: php, code-search-engine

There are a lot of web sites for for PHP developers to copy scripts from. I wonder if there is a "universal" search engine to search examples from all of these sites? Something like a Google custom search engine which searches PHP examples from good web sites. My wife needs a tool like that and I guess this question should be sent to the PHP gurus here. Thank you in advance.

BTW, There is a useful search engine for Java examples here: http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=004472050566847039233:9ld3aazskua

JB

Comment: PHP doc has lots of user provided code. Sadly though Google code search doesn't let you search just withing a site like regular web searches.

Comment: Why don't you build your own Google Custom Search engine from the web site you mentioned? Just like the Java example.

Answer (score 3):

What about http://www.google.com/codesearch?

Comment: Hmm that search engine doesn't give me the results I need. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Maybe if you posted specifically what you were looking for here, someone could give a better answer?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one
http://www.koders.com/

Comment: in that case, maybe just using php.net, the docs have heaps of user submitted examples

Answer (score 1):

For Google, start you search term with `filetype:phps <?php` to search for source files.

[Php search for foo](http://www.google.nl/search?q=filetype:phps+<%3Fphp+foo).

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://www.krugle.com/

Answer (score 0):

On the [PHPClasses](http://www.phpclasses.org/) website you can find a class for just about everything, and it has the search capability.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found that php.net have great examples. and if there isn't something in the main article the comments will usually have what your looking for.
You can view the massive list of functions here: http://www.php.net/quickref.php

for people just starting to learn php then W3Schools is an excellent recourse.
I also used TiZag greatly when I learnt php
(just do a google search for W3Schools or TiZag)